# Automate browser actions - get_iframe with last.click

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, splinter

When I use the event `last.click()` does not generate any error but the event is not running (`is_element_present_by_xpatch return true`).

```
from splinter import Browser
import time 
from time import sleep
import unicodedata
from unicodedata import normalize
import sys
import os, random, time, unicodedata

login='9999999'
pwd='9999999'

browser = Browser()
browser.visit('http://www.yasudamaritima.com.br/saude/')

with browser.get_iframe(0) as iframe :
    iframe.fill('cdcodigo',login)
    iframe.fill('cdsenha',senha)
    #I Try : iframe.find_by_tag('img').last.click()
    #and try: iframe.find_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/img").last.click()

this code is working:

browser = Browser()
#browser.visit('http://www.yasudamaritima.com.br/saude/')
browser.visit("https://websaude.maritimaweb.com.br:444/ace/acesso_prestador.asp")
browser.fill('cdcodigo',login)
browser.fill('cdsenha',pwd)
browser.find_by_tag('img').last.click()
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I tested you code, and it only have a minor error:

```
iframe.fill('cdsenha',senha)  # pwd ?
```

I modified a little:

```
with browser.get_iframe(0) as iframe :
    iframe.fill('cdcodigo', login)
    iframe.fill('cdsenha', pwd)
    #I Try :
    img = iframe.find_by_tag('img').last
    print img
    print img.outer_html
```

the result:

```
~$ python sp.py 
<splinter.driver.webdriver.WebDriverElement object at 0x7f7b4bc56e50>
<img src="enviar_novo.jpg" onclick="carregarpagina()">
~$
```

It seems there is no problem.